# Modify a single option in a select and show changes without clicking into select

Tags: html, jquery, css, select, html-select

I have a form that contains a `select` with several `options`. One `option` can be selected by default based on a value in the DB.

If an option is selected by default, we want to apply some styling to it.

Once the form is rendered, I can simply do something like this...

`$('#mySelect option:selected').addClass('customClass');`

Lets say `customClass` just makes `background-color:green`.

What happens is that once the form is loaded, the option is still default white in the select. It only turns green once you click on the select.

I think this is because only the option is being changed to green.
If I do, just `$('#mySelect').addClass('customClass');` then all options are green.

I thought about applying the class to the whole select and then looping through all options and removing the class except for the selected one, but that doesn't seem efficient.

Any ideas of a concise way to do this?

Thanks!

Here's a simple example
[almost working example](https://jsfiddle.net/z8p5ceq0/10/)

Comment: `option` styling is very unreliable and will differ in different browsers. It would be better if you create a custom dropdown(which is made from divs and such) to do this kind of thing

Comment: Your issue isn't that it's "*only green once you click*", it's that it's only green in the options drop down, the "selected" part (closed drop down) isn't styled.  (at least in my browser...)

Comment: Makes sense, is there any way to style it inside the select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/o81hyseg/

```js
$("#mySelect").on("change", function(e){
    if(!e.isTrigger)
           $(this).find("option").removeAttr("selected");
      
   if($("#mySelect").val() == "green"){
      $('#mySelect').addClass('foo');
      $('#mySelect').attr('title', 'foo');
      $(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex]).attr("selected","");
   }
   else{
      $('#mySelect').removeClass('foo');
      $('#mySelect').removeAttr('title', 'foo');
   }
});

$("#mySelect").trigger("change");
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: green;
}

.foo option:not([selected]) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option selected>green</option>
  <option>white</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I had something similar, but options other than 'green' still turn green when selected. I need only green to green

Comment: Pls check out https://jsfiddle.net/z8p5ceq0/10/, we are almost there

Comment: I have updated the answer and demo link as per your concern.

Comment: Almost! One last edge case (my apologies if my requirements are not concise). 
I would like the `green` option to always have its styling (be green and have that title).

Notice that if you select 'white' this removes the styling from the 'green' option.

Is this possible to implement? Thanks!

Comment: Figured out my last edge case by unconditionally setting the specific option's (Where green in this example) styling and title

Comment: for that add css class to particular option and apply styling.

Comment: for e.g. add foo class to green option.